# How can i correctly compare lists using python?

Tags: python, loops, cursor

I have two tables and i want to append of values of some fields in a list.My code does not iterate correctly because rowt[2] is not correct for each of code2 values in the list .The values of code2 in table1 must be identical with code2 in the table2.Also in performance consideration the code is very slow. How can i fix the problem and How can i improve the performance?

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table1,["Code1","Code2","Code3"],where_clause = sqlfinal) as curtable:
    for rowt in curtable:
        s = rowt[1]
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table2,["Name","Code2","Code4"]) as curs:
            for rows in curs:
                if rows[1] == rowt[1]:
                   vtab.append([rowt[0],rows[0],rowt[2]])
            parameters[5].value = vtab
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: @ettanany I fix it